# How do I input my link information in html5 from a swiffy created from a flash file?

Tags: html, flash, flash-cs5

I'm creating a banner ad in flash cs5 with AS 2 and converting it to html5 with swiffy, I have a button with a click tag in flash, but where do I input the link information for my click tag - in the html, in flash or is it input somehwere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to add something:

for the purpose of running this flash/html5 thru a adserver, the URL inside the flash doesn't really matter, you could have one inside the flash and another one on the codeside; The click will use the one on the code side.

So yuo could have inside the flash:

```
on (release) {
getURL("http://www.msn.com", "_blank");
}
```

and, after the conversion, the related code would be:

```
"actions":[{"value":"http://www.msn.com","type":305},{"value":"_blank","type":305}
```

Now you could actually replace the URL like this:

```
"actions":[{"value":"http://www.google.com","type":305},{"value":"_blank","type":305}
```

and the banner would go to google instead of going to msn.

note that I also added the target _blank.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of Flash banner ads, but never have to supply any HTML to the publisher, just a .swf and backup .gif.
Publishers specifications vary greatly but generally, when supplying to the publisher, tell them the URL that the clicktag needs to redirect to.
It is the publisher who will implement the URL.
Hope that helps
:)

Answer (score 0):

I just did an AS 2 button with

```
on(release) {
getURL('http://www.google.com');
}
```

Exported as SWF and uploaded that to Google's [Swiffy converter](https://developers.google.com/swiffy/). It generated HTML5 code with the link (snippet):

```
"actions":[{"value":"http://www.google.com","type":305},
```

The button works. So, put the link in your Flash source file. If you ever need to change the URL, you can do it by text-editing the html file.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use js to link the container:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>

$('#swiffycontainer').click(function() {
            window.location.href = "http://yourWebSite.co.il
    });
```